# How to generate predictions using frozen_model.pb file?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving

My model is CNN for text classification. I am referring ([here](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc)) to freeze models into .pb file. I have trained models to 4 epoch and my checkpoints folders look as follows:

[image]

I have exported the models into frozen graph as shown above. How do I generate predictions directly from frozen graph ? There exists documentation to generate predictions from model files ([I am refering here](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf)). But how do I generate predictions using only frozen_model.pb file?

Comment: We recommend that you use SavedModels and tf serving instead of relying on frozen graphs for predictions; that codepath is far better tested and supported.